# Using Ajax With jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to show a dialog which gets its content from server dynamically using ajax. If I use this

```
$('a.key').click(function(){
          var resp = 'grk';
          $dialog.html(resp);
          $dialog.dialog('open');
          return false;
      });
```

everything is perfect. When I click the link it shows me the dialog box. But If I try to do what I want which is to call ajax to fill the dialog content. It just does not work. I am very new to jquery please help.

This is the code that I use to call ajax and it does not work.

```
$('a.key').click(function(){
          var resp = 'grk';
          resp = $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "/cms/getdata",
               success: function(msg){
             }).responseText;

          $dialog.html(resp);
          $dialog.dialog('open');
          return false;
      });
```

Thank you..

Comment: What exactly is `.responseText` at the end of your `.ajax` call in the non-working code? You also have some brace-parenthesis mis-matches I would look in to first before you get too far debugging.

Comment: I had to look it up myself. It is supported; you'll have to search for it to see it in use: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$('a.key').click(function(){
      var resp = 'grk';
      resp = $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/cms/getdata",
           dataType: "html",
           success: function(msg){
            $dialog.html(msg);
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            }
           }).responseText;


      return false;
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer but it doesn't work. I think i am doing something wrong.

Comment: check also dataType, also you can do alert(msg); before $dialog.html(msg); to check the result of return

Comment: It's missing a closing } for $.ajax. The } in }).responseText is the closing bracket for the success function.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the asynchronous and non-blocking nature of JavaScript you must provide a callback which is executed once the ajax response has arrived. You can also use the [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) shortcut.

```
$('a.key').click(function() {
    $.get("/cms/getdata", function(data) {
        $dialog.html(data);
        $dialog.dialog('open');
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is the $dialog actions are occurring while the ajax request is still occurring. What you want to do is encapsulate the commands after the response is returned.

Doh! Yuriy beat me to it.